# Threejs globe glow issue

Tags: three.js

We are trying to achieve a glow around a sphere/globe using this code :

```
var sphereGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 40, 40);
var moonTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
  "../../assets/moon-map.png"
);
var moonMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: moonTexture });
var moon = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeom, moonMaterial);
moon.position.set(0, 0, 0);
this.add(moon);

var customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    c: { type: "f", value: 0.4 },
    p: { type: "f", value: 2.3 },
    glowColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0xffffff) },
    viewVector: { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3(10, 10, 10) }
  },
  vertexShader: `uniform vec3 viewVector;
  uniform float c;
  uniform float p;
  varying float intensity;
  void main() 
  {
      vec3 vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
      vec3 vNormel = normalize( normalMatrix * viewVector );
      intensity = pow( c - dot(vNormal, vNormel), p );
      // intensity = 0;
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
  }`,
  fragmentShader: `uniform vec3 glowColor;
  varying float intensity;
  void main() 
  {
      vec3 glow = glowColor * intensity;
      gl_FragColor = vec4( glow, 1.0 );
  }`,
  side: THREE.BackSide,
  blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  transparent: true
});

moonGlow = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeom.clone(), customMaterial.clone());
moonGlow.position.set(moon.position.x, moon.position.y, moon.position.z);
moonGlow.scale.multiplyScalar(1.1);
this.add(moonGlow);
```

This all looks good and we are getting the desired result. BUT when we are setting the WebGLRenderer’s alpha to true (for getting a gradient in the background body element) then the whole glow is being surrounded by a black border.

**Is there some way for getting a gradient color in the background and in the front showing this sphere with glow?**

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a texture to `scene.background` to achieve the desired effect. In this case, it's not necessary to apply `alpha = true` to `WebGLRenderer`.

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = loader.load( 'textures/gradient.jpg' );

scene.background = texture;
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/4946/